# How to publish the asset components of a package without timestamp on the name on Github Packages by using Gradle and GitHub Actions?

Tags: gradle, github-actions, github-packages

I'm using a Spring Boot app with Gradle as build tool on GitHub repo and I'm going to publish the release version already packaged on GitHub Packages to be ready to deploy in the cloud.

The workflow has been made with GitHub Actions and I have already been able to publish the package on the GitHub Packages.

My requirements are:

- I'd like to avoid publishing the assets of the package with timestamp as following image:

  [image]

  but I'd like to have in the standard format like [this example](https://github.com/emyasa/spring-authorization-server/packages/1253247)
- Once that the specific release is done (e.g 1.0.0) and the related package is published on GitHub Packages, I want to avoid overwriting the package or appending the assets to the package.

In a nutshell I want to avoid to create another package version if it is already present.

GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: Publish-package-on-GitHub-packages
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
        environment:
          description: Target environment
          required: true
          type: environment
          default: dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
        contents: read
        packages: write
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: packaging workflow  
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: |
          chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name : Get App Version
        id: get-app-version
        run: |
          echo "APP_VERSION_NAME=$(${{github.workspace}}/gradlew -q printAppVersionName)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      
      - name: Print App version
        id: print-app-version
        run: |
          echo "app version: ${{env.APP_VERSION_NAME}}"

      - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1

      - name: Publish package
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          gradle-version: 8.5
          arguments: Publish
        env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

`build.gradle`:

```kt
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

ext {
    group = 'com.xx'
    name = 'app_name'
    version = '0.1.0-feature_name-SNAPSHOT'

}


java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.2.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

task printAppVersionName {
    doLast {
        println project.ext.version
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/org_name/repo_name"
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
                password = System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }

    publications {
          gpr(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
            groupId = project.ext.group
            artifactId = project.ext.name
            version = project.ext.version
        }
    }
}
```

Can you give me any suggestions to get my requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to set the version app with semver standard I have satisfied my first requirement. I suppose that the GitHub Packages is only thought to publish the release packages.

eg 0.3.0 version as showed in the image below

[image]

In addition I have satisfied my second requirement, because after the first publish package if I run againg the workflow with the same release version I get

```
status code 409 from server: Conflict
```

[image]

I say that the behavior is correct following the best practice